# $text - $search aggregation after lookup mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to search by a *keyword* into the documents of my DB and I have found [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/) on mongo's official site documentation. However, I have few problems:

1. I need to make a lookup first, and mongo wants the `$text` search as the first pipeline, so If I make after that the lookup then I exclude the fields from the lookup.
2. I need to search only between some fixed fields and not everywhere.

For example my documents looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('60dcb67ebe94846b27402dc7'),
  field1: "dada",
  field2: "lalala",
  field3: "nanana",
  creator: ObjectId('632cb67ebe94846b27402dc1')
}
```

I Need to search in `field1`, `field2` and some fields from *creator*, let's say `creator.name`, which I'll have got after doing the lookup. According to the documentation first thing first I have to create an index so let's do it on `field1`. After that I have to put the `$text` aggregation in a `$match` pipeline, but as its first one.

Do you think it is possible to do first the lookup and after that the $text search? Also is it possible to specify the fields to search in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform text search queries, you must have a **text index** on your collection. A collection can only have one text search index, but that index can cover multiple fields. You cannot create test index spanning multiple collections.

Also, The `$match` stage that includes a `$text` must be the first stage in the pipeline.

Comment: I see thank you. What about if I want to search in `field1` and `field2` but NOT in `field3`?

Comment: You can create a text index combining `field1` and `field2` and then search with`$text` operator. Also if your fields are not very large, can consider [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)